# removed log dir now jetty fails to start

Tags: ubuntu, jetty

I have a jetty server that deploys a war file.  Everything was working great until I decided to tidy up the logs.  I had successfully done this on another jetty server of mine but I think I forgot the * on this command:
rm rf /opt/jetty/logs 
so it removed the logs directory as well.  Now jetty fails to start using the service jetty start or service jetty restart command line (with or without sudo elevation).  I've re-created the logs dir but still no luck.  Is there a solution for this?  This is a jetty 9 deployment.

Comment: A permissions issue?

Comment: Note: `/opt/jetty/logs` is not a standard logging output directory for Jetty, something you are using has customized/configured Jetty to not use the standard `${jetty.base}/logs` directory.

Comment: hm. thanks for responding. after I recreated the directory I changed permissions to 775, but still failed to start. unfortunately, I didn't set this vm up so I'm not sure how Jetty was configured.